# How to substring from character to end of string?

Tags: c#, substring

Old: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

New: `/questions/ask`

I want to get the string from the third "/" character onward.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A crude but working example. you can further improve upon it. Call

```
    GetEverythingFromThird("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", "/");
```

The method:

```
static string GetEverythingFromThird(string instring, string checkitem)
        {
            string outstring = "";
            //1st occurence
            int index = instring.IndexOf(checkitem);
            outstring = instring.Substring(index + 1);
            //2nd occurence
            index = outstring.IndexOf(checkitem);
            outstring = outstring.Substring(index + 1);
            //3rd occurence
            index = outstring.IndexOf(checkitem);
            outstring = outstring.Substring(index);
            return outstring;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd be far better off creating a Uri for this:

```
Uri u = new Uri("http://host.com/path/part");
Console.WriteLine(u.PathAndQuery);
```

Not everything that is a string should be manipulated as a string, particularly when the content has some deeper meaning/representation (JSON, XML, dates etc)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: eg
old : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57050007/how-to-substring-from-character-to-end-of-string
new: /57050007/how-to-substring-from-character-to-end-of-string


solution URi is not work.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say there but it sure doesn't obey your "everything after the third /" rule

Comment: i want collect all string "everything after the third / " . please help. my english very poor

Answer (score 0):

Just use regex. Something like this should work fine.

```
Match res = new Regex(@"(?:.*?\/.*?\/.*?)(?<YourString>\/.*)")
    .Match("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask");

if (res.Success)
{
    return res.Groups["YourString"].Value;
}
```

Though if you are going to work just with urls solution by Caius Jard is go to.